# android view momentarily shows at final position before animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm animating a view to slide upwards to its final position as we enter the activity. My problem is that the view momentarily appears at final position  at the beginning, then jumps to initial position and then the animation begins. How can I prevent this?

**Code**

```
protected void onResume() {
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    super.onResume();
    Animator animator = new ObjectAnimator();
    animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,R.animator.slide_up_lock_icon);
    //animator.setStartDelay(500);
    animator.setTarget(mImageView);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    animator.start();
```

**Animator XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="translationY"
    android:valueFrom="500"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:startOffset="500"
    />
```

setting and resetting visibility helps somewhat, but the animation does'nt work as expected always

Comment: You can try setting it to invisible as default via XML and then make it visible when you start the animation as you do now, but maybe being invisible from the beginning makes it not to show for that moment before making it invisible programmatically

Comment: yes, but that only works when `onCreate()` is called and anytime we return to this screen while it's in the background that doesn't work. I tried adding `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` in `onPause()`, but that doesnt work either. the view still stays visible initially

Comment: where is your default ImageView position? Where the animation ends? or at the first position of the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **move** the `mImageView` to position from where it will start animating.

One way is to do  `mImageView.setTranslationY(500)` before animation starts..

Like this :

```
 mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 mImageView.setTranslationY(500);

 Animator animator = new ObjectAnimator();
 animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,R.animator.slide_up_lock_icon);
 //animator.setStartDelay(500);
 animator.setTarget(mImageView);
 animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
 mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 animator.start();
```

Hope it helps..!

Comment: thank you! why doesn't any android animation tutorial / API Guide explicitly mention this :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could solve your problem.

Activity

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Here tv is your view
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //Create an animation
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up_lock_icon);
    //Set your view's visibility to Visible
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //Start animation on tv
    tv.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Res anim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <translate
      android:duration="1000"
      android:fromYDelta="yourValueHere%"
      android:toYDelta="otherValueHere" />
</set>
```